# C Swapping with shifting bits

Tags: c

Here is a program to swap two numbers with out using temporary variable and using shifting operations:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int a,b,i,j;
    clrscr();
    printf(“Enter two integers: “);
    scanf(“%d%d”,&a,&b);
    printf(“a=%d,b=%d\n”,a,b);
    for(i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        if((a & (1 << i)) ^ (b & (1 << i)))
        {
            a = a ^ (1 << i);
            b = b ^ (1 << i);
        }    
    }
    printf(“a=%d,b=%d”,a,b);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

My question is what is significance of 1 in this program?
I know the method of xoring that works as follows

```
a = a^b;
b = a^b;
a = a^b;
```

but I don't know how above program works?

Comment: Please never actually swap something like that (or even with the 3 line xor version).  Anyway, 1 << x is the same thing as `1` followed by `x` `0`s in binary, so it's just taking advantage of that (it's swapping one bit at a time, I believe).

Comment: This is really inefficient, the worst "swap" implementation I have ever seen, and in addition it has integer overflow if `int` happens only to be 16 bit wide. Where did you get that cruft from?

Comment: For every shorthand/smart-alec programming trick like the above `xor`, a kitten gets killed! And a programmer who has to read that will chase and hunt down the person responsible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 has one bit on the rightmost position set. `1<<i` has one bit on place `i` set. This program loops through each bit, and swaps them if they are different.

- `a&(1<<i)` tests if `a` has bit `i` set.
- `((a&(1<<i))^(b&(1<<i)))` tests if bit `i` in `a` and `b` are different.
- `a=a^(1<<i)` toggles bit `i`.

Answer (score 2):

It toggles each bit if only one is set.

c = a & (1 << i) = true if the ith bit of a is set

d = b & (1 << i) = true if the ith bit of b is set

```
| c | d | Action          | c' | d' |
-------------------------------------
| 0 | 0 | Do nothing      | 0  | 0  |
| 0 | 1 | Toggle the bits | 1  | 0  |
| 1 | 0 | Toggle the bits | 0  | 1  |
| 1 | 1 | Do nothing      | 1  | 1  |
```

Answer (score 0):

It's similar to the XOR trick, but swaps only a single bit at a time and only if this bit actually differs in `a` and `b`.

`1<<i` has bit `i` set to 1 and all other bits 0.

Also, this does not swap two numbers *without using a temporary variable*. It uses the temporary `i`.